# Sort multiple rows Left-to-Right

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-2010

I have a large excel file which I am trying to *sort* left-to-right by row, been trying to get a `vba` approach to work, but my experience is too low. Surprising how hard it is to do what should be a simple task.

I have tried this code from another post but is mixing them and only 1st row gets arranged.

```
Sub sortfile22()
   Dim keyrange As String
    Dim DataRange As String

    keyrange = "A1:T1"
    DataRange = "A1:T8"

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(keyrange), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range(DataRange)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

My data looks something like this

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20    
48  1   16  40  75  21  50  3   35  73  80  53  33  46  38  2   69  54  63  79    
54  27  62  56  79  67  71  75  28  35  78  66  60  65  5   47  31  38  68  21    
56  77  43  9   64  80  72  16  17  46  10  22  63  34  41  8   53  60  6   79
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 3):

You need to sort each row on its own. Therefore loop row wise through the `DataRange` and sort each `DataRow` on its own.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortRowWise()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Dim DataRow As Range
    For Each DataRow In DataRange.Rows 'loop through all rows of the data
        With ws.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=DataRow, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Rng:=DataRow
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Next DataRow
End Sub
```

So this input data …

[image]

… will sort as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Was actually a bit harder than I expected, but here's the code:

> *I also borrowed, the standard [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) [quicksort](/questions/tagged/quicksort) algorithm,
> courtesy of
> [wellsr.com](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-quicksort-macro-to-sort-arrays-fast/),
> but feel free to use any other sorting algorithm you want, just make sure you change this line of code:*
>
> > `Quicksort sortrow, LBound(sortrow), UBound(sortrow) ' calling QuickSort`

Then the code is executed the following way:

```
Private Sub main()
    
    Dim i As Integer, lc As Long, lr as Long, j As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' finds the last row
    lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' finds the last i-th column
    arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, lc)).Value2
             
    Dim sortrow() As Integer ' sorting each row separately
    
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) ' for every row
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) ' add
            ReDim Preserve sortrow(1 To j)
            sortrow(j) = arr(i, j) ' adding arr elements to SortRow
        Next j
        
        Quicksort sortrow, LBound(sortrow), UBound(sortrow) ' calling QuickSort
        For j = LBound(sortrow) To UBound(sortrow)
            Cells(i, j) = sortrow(j) ' print the sorted results
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Actually the built in sort algorithm can sort left to right `.Orientation = xlLeftToRight` and should be faster because it can use multi-threading while VBA cannot. Actually because of that built in functions should always be faster than self written VBA code. • And you should change to `Long` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: I'm not arguing efficiency here, just an alternative option. Took me quite some time to get it right so might as well post it. As to the `Long`, yeah you are right, though I doubt OP will exceed `Integer` range given his data sats, but for sake of correctness I have edited it

Comment: You could *recode* the loop after `QuickSort` as simple one liner: `Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(sortrow)) = sortrow`. *BTW suggest to fully qualify range references* :-) @Rawrplus
`

Comment: Additional hint: furthermore you could even replace the `sortrow` declaration once by `ReDim sortrow(1 To lc) As Integer` avoiding permanent redimming.

Comment: @T.M. thanks for the input, I'll look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

**Slightly modified array approach**

Just for the sake of the art I modified @Rawrplus' valid & fast solution by reducing three loops to one and by avoiding permanent *redimming*.

```
Option Explicit                                             ' declaration head of code module

Private Sub Main()
With Sheet1                                                 ' << reference sheet via code name, e.g. Sheet1
  ' [1] do some statistics over data range
    Dim i&, lr&, lc&                                        ' declare datatype Long
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row               ' find last row
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column     ' find last column
  ' [2] assign data to array
    Dim arr(), sortrow()                                    ' declare Variant arrays
    arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, lc)).Value2       ' assign range data to 1-based 2-dim datafield array
  ' [3] sort row data and write them back to sheet
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)                ' loop through row data
        sortrow = Application.Index(arr, i, 0)              ' assign current row data to 1-dim sortrow array
        Quicksort sortrow, LBound(sortrow), UBound(sortrow) ' calling QuickSort
        .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(sortrow)) = sortrow   ' write sorted row data back to sheet
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```